# Flexigrid, url to populate grid

Tags: php, mysql, json, flexigrid

I have prepared an application to get data from mysql database (datatype:json and url:post.php) and populate the grid. It works fine but I want to use a method to get the data and not just a php file. Will using a parameterized url be a solution if I pass, for example,
url:post.php?func=getData and later check this in the php file for calling the method? Or are there any better solutions to that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your post.php call functions from a helper file ( a file that contains methods like getData) based on the parameters passed through the flexigrid ajax request. For doing that you will have to modify flexigrid.js file. see how this guy has done it. http://groups.google.com/group/flexigrid/browse_thread/thread/e24c661e4710cdda/e2c494eb00356dd5